# Query result with optimized way with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get data using 4 tables.
**List of Tables**

- numbers
- calls
- ref_label_no
- labels

I want to fetch data no of calls's Number attached with specific labels.
Here is table.
**Number Table** :

```
select id,uuid,number from numbers limit 1;
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
| id | uuid                                 | number     |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
|  1 | ed268b05-758e-44fd-b429-8d5223651814 | 1234561222 |
+----+--------------------------------------+------------+
```

**Call Table**

```
mysql> select id,uuid,did from calls limit 2;
+----+-------------------------------------+------------+
| id | uuid                                | number     |
+----+-------------------------------------+------------+
|  1 | ddddass-b810-4f23-7456-8ff56efab080 | 1234561222 |
|  2 | dddddd-b810-4f23-7456-8ff56efab080  | 123456789  |
+----+-------------------------------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

**ref_label_no Table**

```
mysql> select uuid,number_uuid,label_uuid from ref_label_no limit 1;
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| uuid                                 | number_uuid                          | label_uuid                           |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 7a5e1b6e-0194-4993-8d78-5f7a1b60c7d2 | ed268b05-758e-44fd-b429-8d5223651814 | 7262b06e-9263-4825-8411-4c107104a60b |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**labels table**

```
mysql> select uuid,name from labels limit 1;
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| uuid                                 | name  |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| 7262b06e-9263-4825-8411-4c107104a60b | INDIA |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I want result like Calls number with total calls.[This Output i needed]

```
mysql> select uuid,name from labels limit 1;
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| Number                       | Total_calls  |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| 13456789                     |       2      |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have made below query but no success also taking too much time to response.

```
select count(*) as Total_calls,calls.number as did,labels.name,calls.created_at as callstart from calls, labels JOIN ref_label_no ON labels.uuid = ref_label_no.label_uuid JOIN numbers ON numbers.uuid = ref_label_no.number_uuid where labels.name="INDIA"  group by calls.number;
```

Any Suggestion Or recommendation ?

Comment: what role does `ref_label_no` table play? And why are you using UUID when it seems that you also have an auto increment column on those tables. If you use UUID you don't need a auto increment

Comment: ref_label_no table contains all refrence value like number label and number table uuid, we are using reference value for uuid not based on primary key.

Comment: I am sorry that comment is not very clear

Comment: ref_label_no table contains all reference value like number's uuid and label's UUID,
we are using this new reference table for gather all information uniquely there.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple tables Avoid using join, use **Union**. It will be faster than join.

Like this,

```
select uuid,did from calls union 
select uuid,number_uuid as did from ref_label_no union
select uuid,name as did from labels
```

Comment: but my result also showing wrong,only want result from calls table, but want to filter by labels, any reference query using Union ?

Comment: where to apply where condition ? should i use table alias ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(calls.uuid) as total_calls, numbers.number
FROM numbers JOIN calls ON numbers.number = calls.number
JOIN ref_label_no ON ref_label_no.number_uuid = numbers.uuid
JOIN labels ON labels.uuid = ref_label_no.label_uuid
WHERE labels.name="INDIA"
GROUP BY numbers.number;
```

Since we are calculating the total count of calls grouping by numbers, you won't have the ability to select calls.created_at in the query result because it conflicts with the aggregation function COUNT.

The following query use EXISTS condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(calls.uuid) as total_calls, numbers.number
FROM calls JOIN numbers ON numbers.number = calls.number
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ref_label_no JOIN labels ON labels.uuid = ref_label_no.label_uuid
WHERE labels.name="INDIA" AND numbers.uuid = ref_label_no.number_uuid)
GROUP BY numbers.number;
```

Comment: Used this query, In my calls table have around 1 lk record, and it is taking around 8 minutes to fetch records. It is not work in my case.

Comment: What indexes do you have in your tables? Lack of indexes in tables is the main performance killer. And did it return you the correct results?

Comment: Applied indexing now. As we as this query fetch the record in "20 rows in set (7.64 sec)" times. still 7 seconds is  very big count.

Comment: Indexes should be applied to those join columns as well as where condition columns and group by columns.

Comment: How much data(rows) do you have for each table? I've updated the query to use EXISTS condition to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131779/discussion-between-bean-and-bhavik-patel).